# connecting to google-cloud-platform mysql service with python and query Cloud SQL Admin API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

After downloading the json file I created a credentials object with google.oauth2.service_account, but I don't understand how to connect to the service and start creating API requests.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "path_to_json",
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
```

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. Where are you connecting from? Other GCP services? An external application? I'd start here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

The answer to your questions depends quite a bit on where you're connecting from in terms of how then you connect to the DB.

Comment: Which API do you want to request?

Comment: I am trying to connect from a local application, to sql admin api.
Is that possible to connect with a public ip? or i have to set up a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

I hope documentation [1] could be helpful for you where you will get information about how to connect mysql service using python and also describes how to establish connections to cloud SQL from an application running outside of Google cloud.

On the other hand, documentation [2] about how to enable the cloud SQL admin API. For more examples of using the APIs, please have the documentation Cloud SQL Admin API Reference [3]. Each page has examples calling the API in several programming languages, as well as a request-specific explorer to help you see what goes into a well-formed request and what to expect in the response.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#languages

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api

[3] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest